# BCP utility:"Copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format'"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, bcp

I get below mentioned error when I run BCP command for trusted connection:

> Copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format'.

I tried searching MSDN, where it specifies that servername passed could be incorrect.

The command I am trying is:

> bcp %SQL_database%..TABLE1 in \FileSERVER\file.dat -f\fileserver\Formats\file.fmt -eERR.txt -m1000000 -C -T RAW -S%SQL_server%

When I pass a username and password instead of using the `-T` option, it works. The command is executed from command prompt by passing parameters from command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `-C` and `-T` options are flip-flopped - `-C -T RAW` instead of `-C RAW -T`.

Check the [`bcp` utility's online documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) for confirmation that `-C` rather than `-T` should precede `RAW`.

Try this instead:

```
bcp %SQL_database%..TABLE1 in \FileSERVER\file.dat -f\fileserver\Formats\file.fmt -eERR.txt -m1000000 -C RAW -T -S%SQL_server%
```

My guess is that you probably misplaced the `-T` option when switching to a trusted connection (with the `-T` option) from integrated security (with the `-U` and `-P` options).

Comment: Thanks Joe for pointing it out. I noticed that I also fixed that part...but it is not the issues here. I resolved my issue by trimming SQL_Database. It was having additional spaces so the output was sql_database  ..table1 which was causing this issue.