# Must declare the scalar variable bcp Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, bcp

```
alter PROC XML
AS

DECLARE @myXml xml
Declare @SQL nvarchar(2000)

SET @myXml = 'SELECT TOP 1000 *  FROM [xyz].[dbo].[yzx] FOR XML AUTO'
SET @SQL= 'bcp "exec @myXml" QUERYOUT C:\sample.xml -w -r -t -S www -T' 
EXEC Master..xp_CmdShell @SQL
```

When I run the above code I am getting error as below

```
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 137
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@myXml".
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unable to resolve column level collations
```

Even though I have declared the variable why am I getting the above error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using dynamic sql you need to pass the string value for execution, i think you also need to cast a xml type to varchar maybe this will help:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test1    
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT TOP 1000 *  FROM [xyz].[dbo].[yzx] FOR XML AUTO
GO

CREATE PROC XML
AS
DECLARE @myXml xml
Declare @SQL nvarchar(2000)

SET @myXml = 'dbo.Test1'
SET @SQL= 'bcp "exec ' + CAST(@myXml AS VARCHAR(max)) + '" QUERYOUT C:\sample.xml -w -r -t -S www -T' 
EXEC Master..xp_CmdShell @SQL
```

Comment: These are the errors I am facing if I execute your code
Copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format'.
usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
  [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
NULL

Comment: @user3088731 Please take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398282/bcp-utilitycopy-direction-must-be-either-in-out-or-format

Comment: I think you also need to execute that with a stored procedure. Edit above.